# How to apply dynamicBehavior on multiple objects simultaneously

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops, dynamic

I'm trying to use DynamicBehaviors on Label objects I have just created from a Array.  For this I use the "For In" loop.  All objects get created as expected, but only the last get dynamic.

Maybe I should use the UIDynamicItemGroup, but after many tries, I still don't figure out how to use it.

As you are maybe wondering, I'm new to object oriented programming so I hope it will not be a waste of time for you.

Below the code I have actually.

Thanks in advance.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    var tests:[String] = ["test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8","test9","test10","test11"]
    var viewLabelArray:UIView!


    var label:UILabel!
    var color:UIColor!
    var animator:UIDynamicAnimator!


    var dynamicBehavior:UIDynamicBehavior!
    var collisionBehavior:UICollisionBehavior!
    var countLabel = 0


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let size:CGFloat = 50.0
        var positionX:CGFloat = 60.0
        var positionY:CGFloat = 100.0


        for test in tests {
            label = UILabel(frame:CGRect(x: positionX, y: positionY, width: size, height: size))
            label.center = CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY)
            label.layer.cornerRadius = size * 0.5
            label.layer.masksToBounds = true
            label.backgroundColor = color
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.textColor = UIColor.white
            label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            label.numberOfLines = 1
            label.text = test
            self.view.addSubview(label)

            countLabel = countLabel + 1

            if countLabel == 4 || countLabel == 8 {
                positionX = positionX - 140
                positionY = positionY + 100
            } else {
                positionX = positionX + 60
            }

            let gravity = UIGravityBehavior(items: [label])
            let direction = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 1.0)
            gravity.gravityDirection = direction


            let bounce = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [label])
            bounce.elasticity = 1

            let boundries = UICollisionBehavior(items: [label])
            boundries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

            animator = UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view)


            animator.addBehavior(bounce)
            animator.addBehavior(boundries)
            animator.addBehavior(gravity)


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Well you only have one `UIDynamicAnimator`, and you're overwriting it with every iteration of the array. Only that last overwrite will persist

Comment: Also, please fix all the implicitly unwrapped optionals. They're going to byte you in the ass.

Comment: Get it? BYTE... hah.

Comment: Thank you Alexander.  I understand the issue and will find a way to fix it.  Also for the optional (not a good habit indeed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified some line of your code and it's perfectly working for me.

Thanks to [Alexander Momchliov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander-momchliov)

```
var animatorArray = [UIDynamicAnimator]()

for (i,test) in tests.enumerated() {
    //code
    let bounce = UIDynamicItemBehavior(items: [label])
    bounce.elasticity = 1

    let boundries = UICollisionBehavior(items: [label])
    boundries.translatesReferenceBoundsIntoBoundary = true

    animatorArray.append(UIDynamicAnimator(referenceView: self.view))
    animatorArray[i].addBehavior(gravity)
    animatorArray[i].addBehavior(bounce)
    animatorArray[i].addBehavior(boundries)
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ashok.  Got your goal by creating an Array of UIDynamicAnimator, but doesn't work for me.  Is your "[i]" refers to a loop (I get a unresolved identifier)? Getting closer I think.

Comment: i updated it please check. let me know if your facing any problems :-)